# Can I trust the http Host header in this context

Tags: http

I have a microcontroller, connected to my WLAN, that hosts a tiny web server. I can reach the http server via 2 ways :

- either via a domain (admin.example.com) which acts as a reverse proxy to the ip of the microcontroller.
- or via the software enabled access point (192.168.0.49) spawned by the microcontroller.

If I reach the server via its domain, i print a login form to the user.

If I reach the server via its local ip in my local network, I want to skip this authentication process (if the user managed to connect to the SoftAP, or is part of the local wlan, I assume he's trusted). Thus I intend to rely on the http "Host" header, like so : If "Host" equals "192.168.0.49" then consider we are authenticated and skip the username/password form.

Is this a safe approach? Can I trust the "Host" header in this context and with such a use case, or can some evil-doer get around this and gain access?

Comment: Does "*software enabled access point spawned by the µc*" mean it is connected to the home WLAN, or is that a separate WLAN?

Comment: Why don't you just move the authentication over to the proxy and leave the µC completely open? That sounds like both easier to set up and possibly more secure.

Comment: @TooTea Because I want the credentials to be editable by the end-user. I store them sha1 hashed in the EEPROM.

Comment: @Bergi Soft AP is when the µc acts as a hotspot. It broadcasts its own SSID you can connect to. Once connected to it you can browse the webserver it hosts (http://10.10.13.37). On top of that, the µc also acts as a station, that means it can connect to your home WLAN. To sum up : ```admin.example.com``` hits a dedicated server at a 3rd party datacenter, which proxies the request to your home wlan router, which routes the request to the µc. The AP is for my fallback procedure in case there is an outage (internet down, router down, server down, etc)

Comment: @Musa Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to remark that there are *three* ways to reach the http server then: via the reverse proxy, via direct connection in your home WLAN, and via direct connection in the hotspot WLAN.

Comment: @Bergi That is correct. ```admin.example.com``` + ```192.168.13.37``` + ```10.10.13.37```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

One can connect to admin.example.com, port 80, and send this request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.49
Connection: Close
```

And it will bypass the authentication.

The `Host` header is not used for that. It's intended for clients to ask for the host they want to connect when the server hosts more than one server on the same address. And it's all controlled by the client, so the client can pass whatever Host header he wants, even none.

What you can do is to check the IP of the client. If the IP is on your LAN and the IP is not the router, it's coming from the internal network.

The address of the router should not be trusted is because of NAT. Depending on your setup, and a myriad of factors, UPnP can open a port on your router to the internet, and the IP reaching your microcontroller would be the router, not the external client.

Even if you are using a reverse proxy in front of your microcontroller, is possible to an attacker to abuse UPnP and create a direct connection to your network.

Comment: Would this bypass work if I force a connection close after I have served each http request? As far as I understand, this bypass relies on the fact that the attackers maintains the successfully open tcp connection at admin.example.com in order to fake the Host header afterwards?

Comment: It does not change anything. If you close the connection, the attacker starts another with the appropriate Host header and bypasses the authentication again.

Comment: `curl -v --header 'Host: 192.168.0.49' admin.example.com`

Comment: @Musa "*connect to admin.example.com, port 80*" is misleading. It actually means "lookup the ip of admin.example.com (in the dns or elsewhere), then connect to that ip address on port 80". The TCP connection has no knowledge of the domain name.

Comment: In my mind, it meant : "lookup the ip of ```admin.example.com``` in the dns and see where the ```admin.``` subdomain leads in the ```root``` defintion of Nginx conf. Oh, ```admin.``` is a proxy_pass, so let's go to ```ip_of_the_microcontroller```. If one sends ```Host: 192.168.0.49```, I have no idea what that virtual host is so I will send you a default page." Hence the confusion. Still not very clear to me how this all articulates. I will play with those cURL commands to picture it better. Thank you all.

Comment: @Musa Actually, I think you're right that ThoriumBR missed something - the server at admin.example.com doesn't directly host the service you're securing, it _proxies_ it. So the requests you need to distinguish are _direct requests_ (inside the network) and _requests from a proxy which you control_. I'm not sure the Host header is the _best_ way to distinguish those, but it does make it easier for you to control things, because the proxy can reject or manipulate incoming requests.

Comment: @Musa Oh, I missed that it's a reverse proxy not just a DNS alias

Comment: NAT doesn't usually change the source address of incoming packets to the router's IP.

Comment: @Barmar I've worked with so many types of NAT gateways that I've seem everything...

Comment: At least on Linux iptables if you neglect to set appropriate scopes on a SNAT or MASQURADE rules it's easy to end up performing source NAT on every connection that passes through the NAT box, including port forwards.